# How do I prevent Rails from loading assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

An understandably weird question. I'm porting a project to RoR, in order to use some of its components. Asset management is not one of them.

I wind up with something like this in my page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Opera</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/main.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/main.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="5YFRzv/wICYBms8cregzthpFqCr5gf3pQknNpLOOeEg=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- My scripts and stylesheets below -->
```

What do I do differently such that the page doesn't load its own scripts and stylesheets?

Additionally, if I link stylesheets in the `.erb` template, they all wind up under the `<body>` tag. The Rails stylesheet/script helpers assume that your stuff is in the `/asset` directory.

How do I get Rails to link my scripts under `<head>` if I've placed my scripts and stylesheets in `/public`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default scripts and stylesheets are loaded because of the following two lines in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Rails uses the layout defined in the file `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` as a default for rendering any view. The views go in the body part of `application.html.erb` while rendering.

You can remove the unwanted js from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file and css from `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file. You can also specify your own assets in these two files.

I am not sure about `/public` level. Rails pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations: `app/assets`, `lib/assets` or `vendor/assets`.

Read more details for: [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)